# Meteor scaffolding for HTML templates

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, scaffolding

I've just bought an HTML template and I'm trying to work with it with Meteor.js in an iron scaffold. But I don't know where to place the js inide the template. This template is using this js files:

```
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/flickr.js"></script>
  <script src="js/flexslider.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/masonry.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/twitterfetcher.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/spectragram.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ytplayer.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/countdown.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/smooth-scroll.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scparallax.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

This is my scaffold.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ixws.png)

Could anyone knows where do I need to put my js files?

Those are the errors I'm getting:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
```

Comment: Just to add, I'm placing those files in the public folder and calling them on master_layout.html but I'm getting some JS errors in the console.

Comment: `app/public/js` should work I believe.  Can you edit your post to include the errors you're getting in your console?  You can also just put the files inside of the client side lib ie: `app/client/lib` without including them in your layout.  The latter would be a more *Meteor* way of doing it

Comment: @challett added :) JS files are in app/public/js and I'm still getting this issue :(

Comment: Try to use absolute URLs (`/js/...` instead of `js/...`, note the leading slash).

Comment: I've just added in `app/client/lib` However I'm still getting the same errors. Also adding the leading slash if I place them on the public folder. I think is more like the way Meteor loads the js files, and Meteor loads them alphabetically causing this error. What do you think?